# Vulkan/GLSL shader best way to allocate buffer with previously unknown output length

Tags: glsl, dynamic-memory-allocation, vulkan, shader-storage-buffer

I'm writing a compute shader that will output some unknown amount (there is a theoretical upper bound, but it is huge, compared to expected values) of data into a storage buffer.

I have found a way to achieve this: First run a simplified version of the shader that just counts the number of output values. Then use the result from that to allocate a buffer that is large enough and run the real shader writing into this buffer.

But to me that feels inefficient, having a rather big overhead from recording and submitting two command buffers successively, both doing essentially the same, and retrieving the counter from the GPU in between. Is there a better way to do this? From what I have read, maybe Dynamic Storage Buffers could be a solution, but I can't find much information on how they work (an example would be nice) or what they are really intended to do.

Comment: "*From what I have read, maybe Dynamic Storage Buffers could be a solution*" No, it's not. That's about how/when you specify the region of the buffer to be used, not how you determine how much space you need.

Comment: You mention big overhead. Have you measured how much it represents compared to the actual computations that follow? Also, how often do you need to determine the amount of things to output? If it's only once in a while after some user interaction, does it really matter (still, relative to the time the computations that follow take)? Finally, does this output size computation absolutely need to be done GPU-side?

Comment: I have not measured the timings yet, but I will definitely do this at some point. The big overhead is just from experience, whenever pausing the GPU, I am obviously wasting clock cycles. The number has to be determined approximately log(n) times, I maybe did not clarify, that I need close to maximum performance, since that is the main goal of the project. thats why size calculation also has to run on the gpu, since it is massively parallelizeable. There is no user interaction.